# Why do collapsing/expandable iOS UITableView rows disappear on interaction?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to iOS Development and I just implemented a simple expandable sections UITableView. I am not able to understand why some rows disappear and sometimes change position when the row heights are recalculated on tapping the section header. I went through all the already answered questions on this topic and have not been able to find the right solution.

### Following is a scenario:

1. Launch the app:

[image: state-1]

---

2. Tap on the section header:

   - Section expands
   - All other headers disappear

[image: state-2]

---

3. Tap again

   - Section collapses
   - The headers continue to be blank

[image: state-3]

---

4. Scrolled to the bottom and back to the top

   - The positions of headers changed

[image: state-4]

---

5. Scrolled to the bottom and back to the top again

   - The positions of headers changed again with some cells still blank

[image: state-5]

---

### Things I have already tried:

- Wrapping reloadRowsAtIndexPaths in *updates block* (beginUpdates() and endUpdates())
- Using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths with animation set to .none
- Removing reloadRowsAtIndexPaths at all while keeping the *updates block*
- Using reloadData() instead which actually works but I lose animation

---

### Code:

- [Here](https://github.com/muhd-ali/CollapsingSecting) is the link to the project repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're using cells for the header. You shouldn't do that, you need a regular UIView there, or at least a cell that's not being dequeued like that. There's a few warnings when you run it that give that away. Usually just make a standalone xib with the view and then have a static method like this in your header class. Make sure you tie your outlets to the view itself, and NOT the owner:

  ```
  static func view() -> HeaderView {
      return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! HeaderView
  }
  ```
- You're reloading the cells in the section that grows, but when you change the section that's grown you'd need to at least reload the former section for it to take the changes to it's cell's height. You can reload the section by index instead of individual rows in both cases

Comment: thanks for your response. It worked. Can you please explain why does dequeue rows like that breaks the thing?

Comment: I could only guess exactly why it happens because it depends on the inner workings of classes we don't have the code for to be analyzed. But here goes: the cells you're using as headers aren't considered as being used by the table, and it's probably recycled back in the pool, so they get removed from the hierarchy once they get reused in tableView:cellForRowAt: This would cause a mess like the one you're seeing. If you made it work, can you please accept my response?

Answer (score 1):

Ok as you ask, I am changing my answer according to you.

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let rows = 2
    var categories = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 10)

    struct Constants {
        static let noSelectedSection = -1
    }

    var selectedSection: Int = Constants.noSelectedSection

    func selectedChanged(to selected: Int?) {
        let oldIndex = selectedSection;
        if let s = selected {
            if selectedSection != s {
                selectedSection = s
            } else {
                selectedSection = Constants.noSelectedSection
            }

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            if(oldIndex != -1){
                tableView.reloadSections([oldIndex,s], with: .automatic)

            }else{
                tableView.reloadSections([s], with: .automatic)
            }
            tableView.endUpdates()

        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("reloading section \(section)")
        return (selectedSection == section) ? rows : 0;//rows
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return tableView.rowHeight
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return tableView.rowHeight

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Header")
        if let categoryCell = cell as? MyTableViewCell {
            categoryCell.category = section + 1
            let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture))
            recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
            categoryCell.contentView.tag = section;
            categoryCell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

        }
        return cell?.contentView
    }

    func handleTapGesture(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let sindex = recognizer.view?.tag {
            selectedChanged(to: sindex)
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Body", for: indexPath)
        if let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel {
            label.text = "Body \(indexPath.section + 1) - \(indexPath.row + 1)"
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

As you can see now I am just reloading a particular section instead of reloading the whole table.

also, I have removed gesture recognizer from the cell & put this into the main controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I mentioned in my question that I have already tried tableView.reload() and I know it works. But I am interested in knowing why reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, a call that apple provides, isn't working.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please have a look now & let me know if still, it's not working for you.